# Can paired t-test be used when data comes from different task conditions at a single time point?

Tags: t-test, repeated-measures, experiment-design, psychology, research-design

In my experiment a single group of participants performed a cognitive task with two interleaved types of blocks (A and B). Blocks A and B differed in terms of the type of stimuli used but were otherwise the same. There were ten blocks total, five of each kind.

I have performed a paired t-test to compare the performance on blocks A and B and presented the result to my advisor. They argued that a paired t-test was the wrong choice because it can be used only on data collected on the same task (e.g., only A) at two separate time points. They advised to use an independent samples t-test instead.

Are they correct? Even though I somewhat see their point, I feel like an independent samples t-test is not correct either. I expressed my doubt and the advisor suggested a Bayesian approach but were not able to provide instructions on how to perform the test.

I would appreciate a confirmation of who is right, me (paired t-test) or the advisor (independent samples t-test) and a suggestion of a third, more appropriate method if one exists.